# Handle Android action bar search view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I need create action bar search view but I can't handle the search item.

Here is my menu xml item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="Search"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

And I override onOptionsItemSelected method to handle item:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_search:
            System.out.println("press search");

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".app.Search" />

    <activity android:name="com.example.tutorial_search_actionBar.MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>

            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But when I press the search item in action bar 1.my keyboard doesn't have search key
and 2.doesn't print "press search"

What should i do

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourAppName="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      yourAppName:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      yourAppName:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_xml, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    final int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, YourClass.this);
                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }
        });
    } else {
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, YourClass.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);       
}
```